# what can you conclude about the number of solutions of the linear system Ax = b?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a $3\times 4$ matrix. If $$\bf{b = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4}$$ then what can you conclude about the number of solutions of the linear system $A\bf{x = b}$? Explain.

How to solve this? I am trying but did not get anywhere.
Help please.

Comment: What do we know about $a_{1},...,a_{4}$? Are those the columns of $A$?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  The right hand side of your equation, i.e. $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4$ provides no restriction without more knowledge as to what they are.  You need more information.  Or perhaps Thomas E. is right and they are the columns of A?

Comment: The question doesn't specify, but this is a problem about linear combination, I assumed that the a's are column vectors. I wrote the question exactly as it is written in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $A$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. If there is no restriction to the vectors $a_{1},...,a_{4}$ then we can not say anything about the solutions. Could be none or could be many.

If $a_{1},...,a_{4}$ here are the column vectors of $A$‚ then recall that the column vectors of $A$ span the range of $A$. So if $b$ is a linear combination of the column vectors of $A$ then $b$ is in the range of $A$. Hence there is at least one solution, call it $x$.

Now note that by rank nullity theorem $4=\mathrm{null}(A)+$rank$(A)$. Here rank$(A)$ is bounded from above by $3$ so $A$ must have a non-empty kernel. Now $x+e$ is another solution for any $e\in$Ker$(A)$. In other words, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: $x=(1,1,1,1)^t$ is a solution.

Comment: @YourAdHere: If you assume that $a_{1},...,a_{4}$ are the columns of $A$, then yes. But in that case there are infinitely many solutions as I pointed out.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand. will u make it more clear please?

Comment: @sovon: Which part did you not understand?

Answer (score 0):

If ai for I=1..4 are the columns then one particular solution is x=(1,1,1,1) as you can easily check to which you can ad the arbitrary vector (I-GA)h for any h and get the whole solution set. For an arbitrary y just  take x=Gy.

Note that G is right inverse of A, such that AG=I (for example G=A'*inv[AA'] if rank(A)=3) and thus AGA=A and (I-GA)h is the orthogonal projection of h into ker(A).

Comment: Why would $A$ have a right inverse? It could be that $a_{1},...,a_{4}$ span something lower dimensional that $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. In fact $A$ could be anything from the null matrix to full rank matrix here.